# Lambda Function: PUT S3 --> Update Table

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am struggling since two weeks with my Lambda Function.

Basically a PUT-Request in my S3-Bucket triggers my Lambda, that runs an SQL Statement, and a table is generated. It should be so, everytime a JSON-File is uploaded in S3.

The problem is that the table (with the data) is generated only for the first file that I upload in the S3-bucket, or when many files "for the first time" are uploaded in the S3-bucket "all together".

How can I overcome this problem? I am new in Python/AWS/... Do you have any suggestion?

Input: When a file is uploaded in the S3-Bucket, the table should be for the first time created and for the other next files the table should be **updated** (writing new JSON Files in S3).

I hope you can help me :)

Thank you in advance!

I paste the code below:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query_1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auswertungen.anzahlmessungen \
    WITH ( format='JSON', external_location='s3://qs-datalake/Folderxxx/' ) AS \
    SELECT S.locationsid AS LocationID, \
    CAST(split_part(SD.datetimestamp, \
    ' ', 1) AS DATE) AS Datum, COUNT(*) AS Counter \
    FROM anreicherungen.sensors AS S \
    INNER JOIN sensordata.sensordata AS SD \
    ON CAST(S.sensorsid AS VARCHAR) = SD.sensorsid \
    GROUP BY  S.locationsid, CAST(split_part(SD.datetimestamp, ' ', 1) AS DATE);"

    database = "auswertungen"
    s3_output = "s3://aws-athena-query-results-eu-west-1-xxxxxxxx"

    client = boto3.client('athena')

    response = client.start_query_execution(QueryString = query_1,
                                        QueryExecutionContext={
                                            'Database': database
                                        },
                                        ResultConfiguration={
                                            'OutputLocation': s3_output
                                        }
                                        )
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the statement `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. This will only create the table when it doesn't exist, which only happens on the first file.

I suggest that you create this table once, and then keep it. If you want to delete previous data before inserting new data, then run a `TRUNCATE TABLE mytable`. Afterwards you can insert all the data from your json file again.

If your database doesn't support `TRUNCATE`, then just add a [DROP TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/drop-table.html) before your statement.